# looking for elegant way to get sub string

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of string like below,

```
var myString = "ABC.XYZ.GrabIt.Delimator.Hello1.Hello2";
            //var myString = "ABC.XYZ.PQR.GrabIt.Delimator.Hello1.Hello2.Hello3";
            //var myString = "ABC.GrabIt.Delimator.Hello1";
```

Over here I need substring before the string `.Delimator` and after the immediate dot, I need only output as `GrabIt`.

I did below try, where I'm splitting the string with value `Delimator` and then trying to grab the string between last 2 dot. looking for a elegant way to do the same? Thanks,

```
var referrer = myString.Split(new[] { "Delimator" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];

            referrer = referrer.Substring(referrer.Substring(0, referrer.LastIndexOf(".")).LastIndexOf(".") + 1).TrimEnd('.');
```

Comment: What's the value you want `referrer` will be?

Comment: `GrabIt`..........

Comment: Perhaps this should help [enter link description here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194716/substring-vs-split-performance-test)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perfect fit for a regular expression.

```
@"(?<=\.)[^\.]+(?=\.Delimator)"
```

In words: look for a non-empty sequence of characters except dot `[^\.]+`, preceded by a dot `(?<=\.)` and followed by the delimiter `(?=\.Delimator)`.

```
var match = Regex.Match(myString, @"(?<=\.)[^\.]+(?=\.Delimator)");
if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't be afraid of code, just as long as its easy to understand and maintainable.

There would be regex solutions, yet this would be probably be faster and is easily readable.

```
var split = myString.Split('.');
var index = Array.IndexOf(split, "Delimator");

Console.WriteLine(split[index - 1]);
```

Obviously no error checking